# SDWebImage thread hogging CPU

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

here is my issue :

I have a `UITableView` containing custom `UITableViewCell`s. Each of those `UITableViewCell` (called `HomePicCell`) is associated to a `Pic` object which has a property pointing to an image URL.
As soon as my cell is displayed, I start downloading this image using `SDWebImage manager`.

Everything is working smoothly, but **after 20 to 80 seconds, some threads start hogging the CPU**. The device then become a perfect hand heater for those cold winter nights, but I'd rather skip this feature for now !

I can't really put my finger on what would cause this issue. I don't think a retain loop would be the problem as it would only hog the memory. An experimented opinion would really help.

[image: hogging threads]

Here is my code :

**UITableView Datasource**

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* cellIdentifier = [@"HomePicCell" stringByAppendingString:[Theme sharedTheme].currentTheme];
    HomePicCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[HomePicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if(self.pics.count>0){
        Pic* pic = self.pics[indexPath.section];
        [cell configureWithPic:pic];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**HomePicCell (configureWithPic:)**

```
- (void)configureWithPic:(Pic*)pic
{
    self.pic = pic;

    // Reinit UI
    [self.progressView setHidden:NO];
    [self.errorLabel setHidden:YES];
    [self.photoImageView setAlpha:0];
    [self.progressView setProgress:0];

    [self.pic downloadWithDelegate:self];
}
```

**Pic**

```
- (void) downloadWithDelegate:(id<PicDownloadDelegate>)delegate
{
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

    [manager downloadWithURL:self.url options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {

        if(expectedSize>0){
            float progress = [@(receivedSize) floatValue]/[@(expectedSize) floatValue];
            [delegate pic:self DownloadDidProgress:progress];
        }

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

        self.isGif = @(image.images.count>1);

        if(image){
            if(cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeNone){
                [delegate pic:self DownloadDidFinish:image fromCache:NO];
            }else{
                [delegate pic:self DownloadDidFinish:image fromCache:YES];
            }
        }else{
            [delegate pic:self DownloadFailWithError:error];
        }

    }];
}
```

**HomePicCell (delegate methods)**

```
- (void)pic:(Pic*)pic DownloadDidFinish:(UIImage *)image fromCache:(BOOL)fromCache
{
    if(![pic isEqual:self.pic]){
        return;
    }

    [self.progressView setHidden:YES];
    self.photoImageView.image = image;
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void)pic:(Pic*)pic DownloadFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if(![pic isEqual:self.pic]){
        return;
    }
    [self.errorLabel setHidden:NO];
    [self.progressView setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)pic:(Pic*)pic DownloadDidProgress:(float)progress
{
    if(![pic isEqual:self.pic]){
        return;
    }
    [self.progressView setProgress:progress+.01f];
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is apparently fixed by switching to SDWebImage 3.0 (instead of 3.3).** 
I'll go ahead and declare an issue on the project github page to see if some people have had the same problem.